# cancelAnimationFrame no limpia mi canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Dentro de este canvas

```
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Tenga esta función

```
var estado = false;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function frame(){
  actualizar();
  coliciones();
  dibujar();
  bucle = requestAnimationFrame(frame);

}

function startStop(){
  if (!estado) {
    estado = true;
    frame();
      console.log('game init :'+estado);
  }else {
    estado = false;
    cancelAnimationFrame(bucle);
    console.log('game estatus :'+estado);
  }
```

pero **cancelAnimationFrame** no borra o no hace un **clear** a mi canvas. Pero si estoy recibiendo los **log's** de mi consola, alguien podrìa decime si hago algo mal?

Comment: cancelAnimationFrame no limpia el canvas,para la animación, Para borrar utiliza `clearRect`

Comment: pero si debe de detener la animación no? como puedo saber si mu animación se detiene?

Comment: Tienes razón: a veces es difícil saber que la animación se ha parado. Una solución sería añadir `bucle="null"` después de `cancelAnimationFrame(bucle);`  Si bucle devuelve `null` es que se ha parado.Pero todo depende de lo que quieres conseguir, La vedad es que necesitaría un ejemplo funcional para poder decir algo más,

Answer (score 0):

La animación no se detiene porque llamas a RequestAnimationFrame al final de la función `frame()`. Para detener la animación desde otra función, o simplemente finalizar la animación, debes ubicar `bucle = requestAnimationFrame(frame);` al inicio de la aplicación.

```js
function frame(){
  bucle = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  actualizar();
  coliciones();
  dibujar();
}
```

Para limpiar el lienzo, escribe después de `bucle = requestAnimationFrame(frame);` el comando `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`. El siguiente código lo resuelve:

```js
function frame(){
      bucle = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
      
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      actualizar();
      coliciones();
      dibujar();
    }
```